# jQuery addClass to a child element

Tags: javascript, jquery, addclass

I have the usual unordered list for a navigation menu with submenus...

html:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Link with submenu</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Sublink 1</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

All of the links inside of the parent `<li>` have a border radius.  But if the parent `<li>` has a child `<ul>`, I don't want the link to have a radius.

I'm currently using this jQuery:

```
<script>
  $("li").has("ul").addClass("sub-radius");
</script>
```

It works fine except it's targeting the `<li>`, but I need it to target the child `<a>` and remove its radius.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this expression:

```
$("li:has(ul) > a").addClass("sub-radius");
```

Edit: If you don't want the sub-items to have border-radii, remove the `>` in the query.

Comment: Worked perfectly.  Thank you all for you quick and awesome answers!

Answer (score 5):

You don't need jQuery here, you can achieve that with CSS alone. Just use the `:only-child` pseudo-class:

```
a:only-child { /* define border-radius here */ }
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/QYaqb/

Answer (score 2):

This should work for your HTML

```
("li").has("ul").children("a").addClass("sub-radius");
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `.find`:

```
<script>
  $("li:has(ul)").find("a").addClass("sub-radius");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

just need to find the a's inside the li:

```
$("li").has("ul").find('a').addClass("sub-radius");
```

here's a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/cBfMV/